# DeepCompare a lot of items as List

Tags: c#, performance, compare

I have a simple data model with around 15 properties (name, age, etc.).

I now have 2 lists: oldData and newData which I want to compare and do something with it. The problem is, the lists are huge (e.g. 1 Million items) and my simple idea of a foreach needs a lot of time (~ 6 Minutes).

How to do it faster?

```
  foreach (var item in oldItems)
            {
                try
                {

                    var actualItem = actualItems.Where(x => x.ObjectId == item.ObjectId).SingleOrDefault();
                    if (actualItem == null)
                    {
                        insertList.Add(item);
                        continue;
                    }

                    // Compare
                    var same = actualItem.ClientId == item.ClientId
                            && actualItem.Contract == item.Contract
                            && actualItem.CurrentNodeOwnerId == item.CurrentNodeOwnerId
                            && actualItem.ExternalInvoiceNo == item.ExternalInvoiceNo
                            && actualItem.InternalInvoiceNr == item.InternalInvoiceNr
                            && actualItem.InvoiceDate == item.InvoiceDate
                            && actualItem.NodeStart == item.NodeStart
                            && actualItem.ObjectNo == item.ObjectNo
                            && actualItem.OrderAmount == item.OrderAmount
                            && actualItem.OrderNo == item.OrderNo
                            && actualItem.PaymentAmount == item.PaymentAmount
                            && actualItem.PaymentCreatedDate == item.PaymentCreatedDate
                            && actualItem.PaymentNo == item.PaymentNo
                            && actualItem.PostingAmount == item.PostingAmount
                            && actualItem.PostingEnterDate == item.PostingEnterDate
                            && actualItem.ProcessWorkflowState == item.ProcessWorkflowState
                            && actualItem.RefInvoiceSource == item.RefInvoiceSource
                            && actualItem.RefInvoiceSourceId == item.RefInvoiceSourceId
                            && actualItem.Status == item.Status
                            && actualItem.TotalAmount == item.TotalAmount
                            && actualItem.VendorName == item.VendorName
                            && actualItem.VendorNo == item.VendorNo;

                    if (!same)
                    {
                        updateList.Add(item);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Log.Error(" Error when compare new ELO list with old ELO List in DWH Service: " + ex.Message + " | for Item: " + item.ObjectId, ex);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Perhaps you should submit this to [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead

Comment: @Innat3 It would need more context before it's welcome on Code Review. We can't meaningfully review the current code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The slow down is probably caused by the line that matches old items with new items. You can speed-up the lookup by creating a [`Lookup`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.lookup-2) for the `actualItems`.

Before entering the loop:

```
var actualItemsLookup = actualItems.ToLookup(x => x.ObjectId);
```

Inside the loop:

```
var actualItem = actualItemsLookup[item.ObjectId].SingleOrDefault();
```

From the documentation:

> A `Lookup<TKey,TElement>` resembles a `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>`. The difference is that a `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` maps keys to single values, whereas a `Lookup<TKey,TElement>` maps keys to collections of values.

Answer (score 0):

Well, 
if you know which property make each item unique this will help , otherwise you can build up some unique key .

**with memory**
you can start with O(n) *O(c) by storing the smallest list into *dictionary/HashMap* with key (unique property),value(the item).

**with no memory** 
you can sort each list and do one pass over both of them with O(nLogn)